# Mysql Server Community Edition With Workbench, How to *completely* uninstall

Tags: mysql

Awhile back I set up mysqlserver to use briefly in a class.  This was some time ago.  Now I suspect my installation has been corrupted somehow and I would like to just completely uninstall it and start over.  However, when I run the install package again, I'm not presented with an uninstall option.  Just options to update.  I tried using windows uninstaller but noticed that some parts remained.

Thank you for your help

Comment: For example, I uninstalled all the mysql components I could find as well as turned off the service but when I reboot... the workbench is still there with the old configuration,  I want to wipe the slate clean and start completely over.

Comment: RESOLVED:  There is actually a start menu option ( on windows ) for mysql installer.  Select that and use the "remove" option.